# Succession de deux verbes conjugués au passé composé

Tags: participe-passé, passé-composé, coordination, auxiliaires

J'ai remarqué qu'en cas de succession de deux verbes conjugués au passé composé comme dans l'exemple ci-dessous, on utilise le verbe avoir conjugué au passé composé suivi par les participes passés de deux verbes.

Quelle est la phrase correcte ?

1. Nous avons effectué quelques simulations simples et essayé d'isoler certaines caractéristiques de la réponse.
2. Nous avons effectué quelques simulations simples et nous avons essayé d'isoler certaines caractéristiques de la réponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux phrases sont correctes.

cf. [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4227) :

> Reprise ou omission des auxiliaires
>
> De façon générale, il est possible de ne pas répéter le deuxième auxiliaire si les verbes coordonnés sont conjugués au même temps et s'ils ont le même sujet et le même auxiliaire. Évidemment, lorsqu'un auxiliaire est omis, le sujet de ce verbe est omis lui aussi. Dans tous les cas, il est possible de reprendre l'auxiliaire et de répéter alors ou non le sujet.

Une troisième forme est donc aussi possible :

3. Nous avons effectué quelques simulations simples et avons essayé d'isoler certaines caractéristiques de la réponse.

La première forme est ici préférable puisqu'elle évite une répétition inutile.

Answer (score 0):

**A/** **Préliminaire**

En une première approche, je crois que la question est passible d'une généralisation assez naturelle et évidente à toutes les conjonctions de coordination. Il semble dommage de s'en passer.

Les conjonctions de coordination sont les mots suivants : **mais, ou, et, donc, ni, car, or**.
Le principe général valide pour les conjonctions de coordination est que la répétition de tous les éléments produit une phrase correcte dans tous les cas (ou presque).

L'ellipse de tous les éléments qui pourraient être répétés est valide dans seulement certains cas, et de plus, seulement lorsque la première indépendante n'est pas trop longue et complexe.

Par exemple, prenant le cas de « et », la possibilité suivante est à la limite d'un bon style ; il est déjà préférable de répéter l'auxiliaire, sinon le tout.

- Nous avons longtemps travaillé sur la solution du problème en conditions anormales de données approximatives et insuffisantes et trouvé des caractéristiques bizarres.

L'ellipse se pratique évidemment seulement si le sujet est le même dans les deux propositions ; l'ellipse du sujet est encore valide lorsque les auxiliaires sont différents mais dans ce cas l'auxiliaire qui correspond à un verbe donné doit figurer.

- Nous avons effectué des simulations et sommes renseignés maintenant sur les possibilités de réaction.

**B/** **Les cas d'ellipse**

L'ellipse de tous les éléments qui pourraient être répétés est valide seulement pour les prépositions « **mais** », « **ou** », « **et** » et « **ni** »;

**1.** forme affirmative du verbe dans la seconde indépendante

*mais*

- Nous avons effectué des simulations mais avons refusé certaines possibilités.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations mais refusé certaines possibilités.

*ou*

- Nous avons effectué des simulations ou avons essayé de modifier des caractéristiques.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations ou essayé de modifier des caractéristiques.

*et*

- Nous avons effectué des simulations et avons essayé d'isoler des caractéristiques.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations et essayé d'isoler des caractéristiques.

L'ellipse du pronom sujet, seul, ne se fait pas avec « donc », ou très peu ; cette ellipse ne semble pas naturelle (subjectif, bien sûr).

- Nous avons effectué des simulations, <s>donc avons trouvé des caractéristiques</s>.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations, donc trouvé des caractéristiques. (*Cette ellipse pourrait ne pas toujours être très idiomatique et il peut être plus sage de ne pas l'utiliser*)

L'ellipse du pronom sujet, seul,  se fait avec « donc », lorsqu'un complément d'objet direct est répété.

- Il a vu venir le projectile de loin, donc l'a évité en se déportant sur sa gauche.

L'ellipse ne se fait pas pour « **car** » et « **or** » ; elle ne se fait pas pour « ni » en raison de l'emploi de cette conjonction seulement à la forme négative.

- Nous avons effectué des simulations <s>car avons manqué de caractéristiques</s>.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations <s>car manqué de caractéristiques</s>.
- Nous avons travaillé car nous avons voulu.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations, <s>or eu des problèmes</s>.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations, <s>or avons eu des problèmes</s>.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations, or nous avons eu des problèmes.

**2.** Forme négative du verbe dans la seconde indépendante

En utilisant une forme négative il n'y a plus la possibilité d'une ellipse de l'auxiliaire, à moins d'utiliser une alternative à la négation habituelle, c'est à dire à moins d'utiliser « **pas** » à la place de « **ne pas** ».

*mais*

- Nous avons effectué des simulations mais n'avons pas refusé certaines possibilités.
- Nous avons effectué des simulations mais pas refusé certaines possibilités.  (*moins formel*)

*ou*

- Nous avons commis des erreurs ou n'avons pas compris le problème à la base.
- Nous avons commis des erreurs ou pas compris le problème à la base. (*moins formel*)

*et*

- Nous avons commis des erreurs et n'avons pas compris le problème à la base.
- Nous avons commis des erreurs et pas compris le problème à la base.  (*moins formel*)

Le cas de **ni**

En corrélation avec « ni » non seulement l'ellipse complète est possible, mais elle est nécessaire.

- Nous **n'avons ni** commis d'erreurs **ni** mal compris le problème à la base.

En corrélation avec « ne » il n'y a pas d'ellipse possible et une inversion « auxiliaire/ verbe » est nécessaire.

- Nous **n'avons pas** commis d'erreurs, **ni n'avons-nous** mal compris le problème à la base.